# Could a blown wing ever be powerful enough to lift an aircraft at zero forward velocity?

Tags: aircraft-design

Theoretically, could an aircraft, using any manner of self generated air flow over the (fixed) wing, ever gain enough lift in order to take off (or just simply lift off the ground) at zero forward velocity?

I am guessing that if an aircraft and its engines were light enough, you might be able to provide a high enough airflow across the wings using the propellers (akin to forward motion) - although obviously I am fully aware that most of the important control surfaces would not be functional. This is just theoretical.

To what end.. well... a more efficient understanding of self-generated lift (possibly?) might result from research into extreme blown flap/wing super-STOL utilization. High-lift, small transport aircraft operating out of small congested city air/heliports with very small runways.

I am aware of the limitations of such designs, such as inefficiency at higher speeds and, in the absence of variable form and geometry (which would add too much weight) the fuel usage would become prohibitive. It's purely an idea for speculation.

Comment: Maybe you should set some limits on your question.  Does it have to be manned?  Would bug or bird sized aircraft qualify?  Would rotating wings (helicopter) qualify as "self generated air flow over the wing"?

Comment: I don't have the data to provide an answer to the question if a plane can fly by self-generating airflow over the wings. What I can say is, there are cases where light planes have become airborne because of very high wings blowing directly to the plane. Here is a video of a parked plane "taking off": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlEKiSwttsc As you can see the plane doesn't generate the airflow over the wings by it self. It's the high-speed-wind that provides the airflow.
- As you can see, the flight didn't last very long ;)

Comment: Yes. It's called a helicopter.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting some sort of engine blowing air across the wings to generate lift. That doesn't make sense. The wing is much, much less than 100% efficient at converting airflow into lift. You'd get massively more lift just by pointing those engines downwards.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That would be a lot more efficient, but not nearly as much fun. :)

Comment: @reirab Killjoy -->

Comment: Ok. I guess I could have asked / or pitched the question slightly differently. Obviously I was referring to fixed wing. And I guess I also meant an aircraft large enough to be considered a passenger carrying craft, although the actual size is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I also should have made it more clear that, I wasn't suggesting that it would be a good idea. In fact, I know that it would be a really stupid idea in practice. I was merely posing a yes/no question of whether a plane (perhaps tethered, if you like, to prevent the airflow providing forward thrust in our imaginary scenario) could achieve positive lift by blowing a self generated airflow of your own wing.

Comment: Yes, and such aircraft are called helicopters. The helicopter rotors work as wings, not as propellers, as they provide lift in the same way fixed-wing aircraft wings do.

Comment: @vsz Helicopters are not fixed wing (see the OP's comment right above yours clarifying that he was asking about a blown fixed wing.)

Comment: I guess an idea of the power required to self-create lift can be obtained looking at a wind tunnel. The aircraft engine power must be similar to the tunnel engines power (prorata the ratio of the aircraft / tunnel sections ratio).

Comment: Just a little physics check here, not meant to be condescending. If the plane self-generated backwards airflow, the reaction to that would push the aircraft forward. In other words, thrust. So you'd get the faster air over the wing, plus faster air from an increasing plane speed too. Best of both worlds. Sounds like what you want is a propeller (maybe with a duct to direct all thrust over the top of the wing).

Comment: You may find some extensive research work on this related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_XFV-12

Answer (score 22):

Technically speaking, yes, it's possible, but wildly impractical.

Of course, as usual, [Jan Hudec's explanation of the physics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/17409/755) is completely correct. Whatever is blowing enough air over the wings to fly would generate an insane amount of forward thrust, meaning that you wouldn't stay at zero forward velocity for long.

**However**, it's completely possible to apply another force in the opposite direction equal in magnitude to what would otherwise be the net forward force produced by the engine(s) blowing the wings. This would yield a total net forward force of zero, thus no forward acceleration would happen, allowing you to take off at zero forward velocity. Of course, you'd want to make sure that whatever is applying this force isn't also blowing the wings in the opposite direction, otherwise you lose your lift.

**Some possibilities for providing this force:**

- Normal jet engines mounted backwards
- Normal propeller engines with negative pitch
- [Rocket engines mounted backwards](https://youtu.be/etzqmtYcpCQ?t=1m4s)
- A (really strong) tether
- Wheel brakes (this only works as long as you're on the ground, of course... you'd start accelerating forwards very quickly as the wheels break free from the ground, but you could technically leave the ground with zero forward velocity.)
- [A really big machine gun](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/), such as the [GAU-8 Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAU-8_Avenger) or [Gryazev-Shipunov GSh-6-30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gryazev-Shipunov_GSh-6-30)
- [Lots of AK-47s](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/) ('lots' being a number roughly equal to the net forward thrust of the engines in pounds divided by 13)

This is roughly what the backwards-mounted rockets would look like:
[image: C-130 Rocket Assisted Landing]
C-130 Rocket Assisted Landing
Source: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/etzqmtYcpCQ?t=1m4s)

Another possibility to technically meet your requirement of taking off at zero forward velocity would be to simply start off rolling *backwards* fast enough that you would accelerate forwards to zero forward velocity at the moment the tires leave the pavement. :)

Of course, as you've hopefully figured out by now, that all of the above are wildly inefficient ways to take off. They would, however, technically work. And, of course, in the case of the GAU-8, whatever is in front of you during the takeoff is going to have a very bad day.

Comment: Zero forward velocity doesn't mean a negative (backward) velocity is ok. It should mean simply this: zero horizontal velocity.

Comment: @jjack That paragraph was a joke. What I described in that paragraph would still have zero horizontal velocity at liftoff. It would just be non-zero prior to liftoff, thus still technically meeting the OP's requirement (as he didn't say it couldn't have a non-zero horizontal velocity _before_ takeoff.)

Comment: I assume simply canting the wings far enough back that much of the lift generated acts to counter the thrust forward has been discarded as a possibility for good and sufficient reasons?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Any AoA that doesn't result in the wing being stalled will still leave a rather large forward force. I was assuming from the way the OP asked the question that he wanted the wing to be generating lift in the normal way (i.e. not stalled.) Blowing the wings just below the critical AoA would be certainly be helpful, but it wouldn't completely eliminate (or even come close to completely eliminating) the forward force.

Comment: @reirab: Fair enough, although I would like to see any detailed calculations/diagrams you can dig up.

Comment: Those speed-braking C-130s were for the purpose of landing in a soccer stadium. Right next to the American embassy.  In Tehran, Iran.

Answer (score 18):

What you're asking for is basically a helicopter: rather than blowing air over the wing it's more efficient to attach airfoils to a vertical axle and generate relative movement (and hence lift) by rotating them.

Comment: I would say, your answer should be: "Yes it's definitely possible - It's called a helicopter" :) Seems to be the best answer IMHO. +1

Comment: I know all of the above, it was merely a speculative poser. It's an absurd question, but I guess I was just wondering whether enough of a pressure differential could be created using self generated airflow over a fixed wing, perhaps tethered to prevent forward motion.

Answer (score 7):

No, it would not.

To take off vertically you need to apply vertical force equal to the weight of the aircraft and no or just a little horizontal force to possibly start moving.

Now the total force on an aircraft (any aircraft) has opposite direction to (average) *change* of velocity of the air flowing around the aircraft, and magnitude proportional to magnitude of the velocity change and amount of the air.

So to lift off, the aircraft has to accelerate air *down* a lot. In normal rolling take-off, the air is moving horizontally around the aircraft, so the wings need to only bend it down a little to generate sufficient downward acceleration and corresponding lift force. But in vertical take-off the air is not moving, so it simply needs to be accelerated downward.

But a *wing* is not capable of bending the flow by 90°, only maybe 30° or something like that, so to give the air enough vertical velocity you'd also give it even more horizontal velocity, generating a lot of thrust.

For all that thrust you would need to provide energy with the engines. It means thrust/weight ratio at least 2:1. No aircraft has that. Conventional aircraft can do with 0.2, VTOLs (including helicopters) need 1 and a bit. 2 is absurdly inefficient. And it would not be true vertical take-off as the aircraft would accelerate horizontally very fast.

With circular shape Coandă effect can bend the air by more, but that does not really count as wing any more. And it still does not have any advantage over rotating the thrust vector itself. The advantage of blowing engine exhaust over the wing is not that it would be more efficient, it is that it is simpler than rotating the engines.

Comment: The last point is the important one - rotating the thrust vector itself is far easier. So I would agree if the question was if it was reasonable to do that. But concerning the possibility, I have three concerns: a) Why would an aerodynamic surface with a 70°-80° deflection angle not be called a wing? b) There are turbofans with a thrust/weight ratio of around 6, so a system thrust/weight of around 2 is not unthinkable (it would look very silly, admittedly). c) You could canel out the horizontal thrust with two counteracting engines (again, silly, but possible).

Comment: @JulianHzg See my answer below. :)

Comment: The acceleration of the flow around the top of the wing relative to the bottom causes a pressure difference between upper and lower wing surface. This pressure difference is called lift. It is not required that the flow leaves the trailing edge at a downard angle. The lift due to bending of the flow is what's called a reaction turbine, which is a different concept. So technically, Jan Hudec's answer is wrong.

Comment: @jjack: You have to remember that _all_ physical laws hold at the same time. Newton's third law requires that if the air applies upward force on the aircraft, the aircraft must be applying downward force to the air and the Newton's second law requires that the air is accelerated downward proportional to the force acting on it since it is free to do so. The forces are created by the pressure differences, but that is totally irrelevant to where the air ends up moving. Newton's laws require it to be down, so down it is.

Comment: Jan, whilst I know that some lift will always be generated via 3rd law momentum reaction, I personally subscribe fully to the pressure difference model of lift. Why? Well, because I am aware of many stol aircraft that can get airborn at 10 knots, with a total downward reaction air weight of just a few kilograms in relation ot the weight of the plane. The enormous lift (as demonstrated by controlled lab measurements using barometric instruments placed above and below the wing) far exceeds any lift generated by 3rd law reaction. I have no clue why it's still disputed.

Comment: @RussBoys, it is still disputed because it is a total misconception that still does not want to die. There is no some lift generated by 3rd law reaction and other lift created by something else. There is just aerodynamic lift and a bunch of physical laws that apply to it and one of those laws is 3rd law: all force the air applies to the aircraft must have reaction force of the same magnitude and opposite direction that the aircraft applies to the air. And since the air does not have any solid support, it accelerates according to the second law.

Comment: @RussBoys, the second law does not require the mass of the reaction air to be comparable to the mass of the aircraft, it just requires that force equals mass time acceleration. The air is accelerated _a lot_. And it also is quite a lot of air: all air within the wing span and to _comparable height_. both below _and above_ the wing. Yes, the air above the wing _is also reaction mass_ and it is also accelerated downwards. It is also applying force (more than the air below the wing, in fact) and the laws of motion apply to it, so it is accelerated.

Comment: Jan is right. Whether you look at the lift as a pressure difference or as the equal and opposite reaction of the force applied to the air (both above and below the wing,) you get the same numbers. Both are just different ways to describe the same thing. There are tons of questions on this SE about how this works.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe.

You would need a very special kind of wing, one which controls the flow direction at the trailing edge by blowing. Such a concept had been tested by [AeroVironment](https://www.avinc.com) in the 1980s and in a model, but to my knowledge no man-carrying airplane using this concept exists.

The cross section of the wing's airfoil is a circle, with an exhaust slot at the back. The exhaust stream of a gas turbine is channeled through the tubular spar of the wing and exits through a spanwise slot in a collar around the spar. By rotating the position of the slot and pumping enough air through it, you can control the amount of [circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_(fluid_dynamics)) this wing creates.

[image: Cross section through tubular wing with rotating exhaust]

The exhaust position of the inboard wing can be used to control lift, like flaps do on a "normal" wing, and the outer part takes over the function of ailerons. By pointing the exhaust straight down and with a sufficient air mass flow, this wing can indeed take off vertically. Efficiency will be nothing to write home about, however.

A blown flap in the conventional sense needs external flow, because its own mass flow is far too small to create sufficient lift. All it does is to invigorate an old, spent boundary layer, so it will stay attached over the contour downstream of the blowing point. Without speed, no external flow exists which could be influenced, except for a small quantity dragged along by the airstream of the blown flap.

A similar, albeit less radical, idea was used in the British research airplane [Hunting 126](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunting_H.126). It used the exhaust gasses from its fuselage-mounted Orpheus engine to blow air over its flaps. Additionally, it had small nozzles at the end of the fuselage and the wing tips for low-speed control, just like the [Harrier Jump Jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Siddeley_Harrier). However, it needed some forward speed to create enough lift to fly.

[image: Hunting 126 in flight]

Hunting 126 in flight (picture [source](http://1000aircraftphotos.com/Contributions/Visschedijk/6897.htm)).

Answer (score 5):

Using the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect), it is theoretically possible for an aircraft's engines to blow enough air over the wing to generate lift.

However, in a real aircraft the engines are placed so as *not* to place the complete wing within their outflow. Otherwise, a large amount of drag would be constantly produced during forward flight. Engine outflow also does not have sufficient cross-section to affect the complete wing, unless a very stubby (small aspect ratio, not very efficient) wing was used.

Applications have been seen in prototypes such as [the Boeing YC-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_YC-14) or production models such as [the Antonov An-72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-72), however these were STOL aircraft, not VTOL.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I didn't consider that. But useful to know for further research.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say vertical takeoff in a non-rotating wing, not deflected thrust machine was obtained in the Custer Channel Wing models, you have some videos in YouTube https://youtu.be/-Sn5JL9t_C4  http://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1952/1952%20-%200044.html http://www.angelfire.com/va3/bythefire/
NASA Technical Report Server -NTRS- has a L53A09 full size wind tunnel report of this arrangement http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930087470.pdf
   and links to the Custer follower's sites exist in Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

A partial "Yes" can be seen if you look at the AvroCar:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_VZ-9_Avrocar

This was never even close to be commercially useful, but it DID fly.

The reason I said 'partial' above, is that some of the lift comes directly from the engine pointing downwards, if I understand correctly, but the whole point of this craft was to investigate the coanda effect.

Answer (score 0):

JulianHzg asked if a surface with a large (70-80 degree) deflection angle could be called a wing.  The Harrier has such a surface.  If we are willing to call the exhaust nozzles "wings" then we have a working example.

[image]

Comment: Exhaust nozzles aren't wings (or airfoils at all,) though. A helicopter is closer to what OP is asking for, since it actually does cause wind to flow over airfoils (the rotor blades) even when it's not moving horizontally, but OP was asking about a blown fixed wing.